# Reference Error when deploying AIR application to android device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am having an issue with my Adobe AIR application for android devices. When running the SWF file on the PC the application runs perfectly, I have also tested this in adobe Device Central and it works as expected. When I install this application to my android device, a HTC Desire HD, I get a screen with 5 dots, seems like a loading screen.

I checked the logcat to see what is going on and it seems there are several reference errors. Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve these?

I created the application using the following command

```
adt -package -target apk-debug -storetype pkcs12 -keystore game.p12 game.apk game-app.xml game.swf icon36.png icon48.png icon72.png
```

This is the contents of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
<id>com.example.game</id>
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
<filename>game</filename>
<name>game</name>
<copyright>me</copyright>
<initialWindow>
<content>game.swf</content>
<visible>true</visible>
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
</initialWindow>
<customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
<allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
<icon>
<image36x36>icon36.png</image36x36>
<image48x48>icon48.png</image48x48>
<image72x72>icon72.png</image72x72>
</icon>
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

</manifest>
]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
<versionLabel></versionLabel>
</application>
```

This is the output from my logcat

```
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): rsl error!
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): numComplete 0
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): numFailed 0
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): numComplete 0
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): failedURLs:
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):   http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.0.0.595/textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):   textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flashx.textLayout.container::ContainerController could not be found.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable introScreen_18 is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable endScreen_1 is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TextInput is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TextInput_upSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TextInput_disabledSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable focusRectSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_upSk
in is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_selectedUpSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_selectedOverSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_selectedDownSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_selectedDisabledSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_over
Skin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_emphasizedSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_down
Skin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button_disabledSkin is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ComponentShim is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Explosion i
s not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Laser is no
t defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Enemy is no
t defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Player is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Explode is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Font_56 is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
I/air.com.example.game( 2623): ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MainTimeline is not defined.
I/air.com.example.game( 2623):
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got an RSL error. You may need to package the .swz file with the APK.

go to actionscript settings  Runtime Shared library Settings and select Merge into code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with very similar output:

```
Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.
rsl error!
numComplete 0
numFailed 0
numComplete 0
failedURLs:
  http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.0.0.595/textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
  textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flashx.textLayout.container::ContainerController could not be found.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable soldsign_24 is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Font_4 is not defined.

Error opening URL 'http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml'
```

I eventually removed the object associated with 'Variable soldsign_24', and 'Font_4' as per the code above. This resolved the compilation error and I was able to salvage my work. I believe this happened to me because of a font I used not being properly linked. Hope that helps :)